# Private iOS API to access raw input from the noise canceling mic(s) on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, iphone-privateapi

Is there a way to use a private iOS API to access the raw input from the noise cancelling mic(s) on the iPhone?

I've tried looking through header dumps I found online but couldn't find anything related to the secondary microphones.

Answer (score 2):

1) One interesting thing which I found on this subject is

```
./System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
```

It has some class called `AUMultiMicNoiseSuppressor`.

2) Make sure that you have the newest header dumps, because a lot of online dumps are for iOS 3.0 (which is outdate)

3) I would recommend to look through frameworks, choose promising and run them through a disassembler. Header dumps usually are dumped with [class-dump-z](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/wiki/class_dump_z), which dumps only Objective-C API and doesn't dump and C API. It could be that API which you are looking for is C API.

Comment: Thanks! And I apologize, I didn't notice your answer until just now. Do you have any recommendations about specifically how to go about finding non Objective-C APIs? Thanks.

Comment: There is no easy way to get signature of non Objective-C API (look here for the question which I have asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511570/getting-signatures-of-private-api-methods-for-ios). Generally speaking, the only way is to disassemble framework and try to figure out arguments. Send me an email (it's in my profile), if you want discuss this in more details (it's just a little bit lengthly for SO)

Answer (score -1):

Have you find the solution to access multiple microphone simultaneously? I'm working on a project just as you mentioned. What I know by far is a record using the build-in microphones doing stereo recording.

https://audioboo.fm/boos/1102187-recording-in-stereo-from-the-iphone-5#t=0m20s

And it is pretty easy on Android. using the Record Class, there are two channels recording the sound from bottom microphone and top microphone (note 3).

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.