# How are headers and functions obtained from iOS private api binaries ? How to reverse engineer an app?

Tags: ios, ios5, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone-privateapi

I have read that class-dump utility is used to dump headers from iphone private api's. However, it does work only for objective-c frameworks. I wanted to know how it works for frameworks written in C, example - IOSurface, IOMobileFramebuffer etc.

The second part of the question is very generic. I have an app with me downloaded from cydia or istore. How do i go about reverse engineering the app on a jailbroken deivce (if that is actually needed). To be specifc, I am able to locate the executable binary and the dylibs. I am able to see the frameworks being used. But, how do I make out what functions inside the frameworks are being called by the app ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that is possible

Comment: Which part - the reverse engineering part or the C framework dump? Because there exist headers for IOSurface, IOMobileFramebuffer frameworks. So, people have done it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to break down this question to two questions:

**1)** *"I wanted to know how it works for frameworks written in C, example - IOSurface, IOMobileFramebuffer etc."*

I had exactly the same question:
[Getting signatures of private API methods for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511570/getting-signatures-of-private-api-methods-for-ios)

The answer is

a) Try to google C method to see whether somebody else has disassembled it and found method signature.

b) If nobody did this before, you can be the first who will do it

**2)** *"how do I make out what functions inside the frameworks are being called by the app ?"*

There are two types of references to functions in frameworks/libraries:

- Compile time references

You use some disassembler, it will list all compile time references to frameworks/dylibs.

- Runtime references

These are references when somebody does `dlopen`, `dlsym` or `NSBundle` to use some functions.
You will have to disassemble and look/grep through disassembled code to find where they are used. There will be strings with the names of methods which are used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used otool on the dylib of the app I wanted to reverse engineer. The resulting assembly code however does not prove to be of much help. I couldn't find function signatures. In case of apple frameworks however I am able to get function signatures. But then getting the arguments becomes a tough job.

Comment: I would recommend you to try Hopper Disassmebler. It's reasonably cheap and it has some interesting function (as example it tries to convert ASM to C like code). This is a nice start to try to learn method arguments.