# Getting method signature of MRMediaRemoteSendCommandToApp from the MediaPlayer.framework private framework

Tags: objective-c, macos, reverse-engineering, disassembly

In particular I'm looking for the method signature of the `MRMediaRemoteSendCommandToApp` method. There is a small amount of information [here](https://docs.ioin.in/writeup/medium.com/_0xcc_a_useless_sandbox_issue_on_both_macos_ios_68597e19b309/index.html) but I wasn't able to make much use of it.

There are definitions available for `MRMediaRemoteSendCommand`, which can look like:

```
typedef enum {
    kMRPlay = 0,
    kMRPause = 1,
    kMRTogglePlayPause = 2,
    kMRStop = 3,
    kMRNextTrack = 4,
    kMRPreviousTrack = 5,
    kMRToggleShuffle = 6,
    kMRToggleRepeat = 7,
    kMRStartForwardSeek = 8,
    kMREndForwardSeek = 9,
    kMRStartBackwardSeek = 10,
    kMREndBackwardSeek = 11,
    kMRGoBackFifteenSeconds = 12,
    kMRSkipFifteenSeconds = 13,
    kMRLikeTrack = 0x6A,
    kMRBanTrack = 0x6B,
    kMRAddTrackToWishList = 0x6C,
    kMRRemoveTrackFromWishList = 0x6D
} MRCommand;
Boolean MRMediaRemoteSendCommand(MRCommand command, id userInfo);
```

As suggested in the [Getting signatures of private API methods for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511570/getting-signatures-of-private-api-methods-for-ios) question, I tried `class-dump` but couldn't find either methods. `Hopper Disassembler v4` showed the correct symbols but I couldn't figure out how to get the method signature for either methods.

Answer (score 1):

class-dump deals with Objective-C classes primarily, this is a normal C function.

```
Boolean MRMediaRemoteSendCommandToApp(MRMediaRemoteCommand command, NSDictionary *userInfo, _MROriginProtobuf *obj, NSString *bundleIdentifier, unsigned int optionSendOptionsNumber, NSObject<OS_dispatch_queue>* queue, void (^block)(NSError *, NSArray <NSNumber *> *));
```

`MRMediaRemoteSendCommand` internally just calls `MRMediaRemoteSendCommandToApp` so the commands are available here: https://github.com/theos/headers/blob/159a952c71bba3e7e3ae68b16d29c7fc549f5cdc/MediaRemote/MediaRemote.h#L79

`_MROriginProtobuf`: https://github.com/w0lfschild/macOS_headers/blob/master/macOS/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote/54/_MROriginProtobuf.h

Example usage:

```
MRMediaRemoteSendCommandToApp(MRMediaRemoteCommandPause, nil, nil, @"com.spotify.client", 0, nil, nil);
```

However after trying that I got the following error in Console.app:
[image]

All commands were redirected to the now playing player.

Creating an app that with the `com.apple.mediaremote.send-commands` entitlement will result in a crash on launch. To prevent the crash you need do three things:

1. Remove the `com.apple.security.app-sandbox` (App Sandbox) entitlement.
2. Do not use an Apple issued signing certificate (Select None for Team in Signing & Capabilities)
   [image: Xcode Sign to Run Locally]
3. Prevent AMFI from checking for the `com.apple.mediaremote.send-commands` entitlement. The method I recommend is using [this](https://github.com/osy86/AMFIExemption) kernel extension.

Comment: This shows the method signature for `MRMediaRemoteSendCommand`. The question is seeking the method signature for the `MRMediaRemoteSendCommandToApp` method.

Comment: Thanks for updating, I'm still unsure how to determine the method signature from the header file though?

Comment: @Dave not sure I understand your question. Header files contain method signatures. Which header file?

Comment: The header file you linked to has the method signature for `MRMediaRemoteSendCommand`. I'm wondering how you discovered which parameters to pass to `MRMediaRemoteSendCommandToApp`?

Comment: @Dave I spent a couple of hours using Hopper, Ghidra, and IDA to see what's going on inside those functions to figure out what kind of parameters those functions are expecting. Sometimes I needed to go 6-7 functions deep. Then I tried passing in the possibly expected parameters to see if it would crash.